# how to setup AWS VPN end point to access SAM Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, vpn, vpc, sam

I have set up a CloudFront based static web site under SAM architecture.

I wanted to setup VPN in between client machine and website by using aws VPN endpoint.
As i knew that i need to setup VPN Endpoint and VPC but have no idea how the VPC access to the Cloudfront based website after successfully established a VPN connection between client VPN and VPC.

Does anyone know how to setup the access to cloudfront from client VPN?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how to setup the access to cloudfront from client VPN?

If your aim is to setup "private" access to your website fronted with CloudFront, then you can't do this without going through Internet. CloudFront is meant to be accessible from the internet.

So even if you setup VPN between your client and VPC, then you have to go through internet anway, through some proxy to access your website.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. does it mean that need to setup internet gateway with VPC in order to access the website.

Client VPN Endpoint > VPC > Subnet > IGW > aws resources like CloudFront